# the result from torch.concat() is stored in cpu(memory)?

Tags: python, pytorch

the code

```
c = torch.rand((2000, 64, 64)).to('cuda')
d = torch.rand((2000, 64, 64)).to('cuda')
t3 = time.time()
s1 = c+d
s2 = torch.concat((a, b), dim=2)
t4 = time.time()
```

s1's device is gpu, but s2's device is cpu.

So I can't understand it. What is the principle of this?

Comment: *a, b* are not defined. `torch.cat((c, d), dim=2)`is also stored on device `cuda`. Btw: Use `torch.rand((2000, 64, 64), device='cuda')` to prevent creating on CPU and copy to GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Torch will do an operation if all the necessary variables for the operation are on the same device.
In your example, we can assume that `a` and `b` were on the CPU. Hence, `torch.concat((a, b), dim=2)` is on the CPU as well. When you write `.to('cuda')`, you move `c` and `d` to the GPU, thus `s1` is on the GPU too.

Comment: Thank you, sir. It's my problem. QAQ

Comment: Glad it heelped ! Can mark the topic as solved if everything is fine ?